# iPhone: UINavigationController not showing new view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have the following action that gets called when a button gets clicked. The log message gets printed yet, the view doesn't change. This function is in a UIViewController.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Why isn't the new view being displayed with a red background?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[levelButton2 addTarget:self action:@selector(clickButton) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
//MORE CODE
}

- (void) clickButton 
    {
        NSLog(@"Clicked Button");
        UIViewController *myViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
        myViewController.title = @"My First View";
        myViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

        //to push the UIView.
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];

        //[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];
    }
```

Comment: are you sure self.navigationController isn't nil? Set a break and step through the code with the debugger don't just log a line.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's nil - I gotta check. I did not instantiate it though. Do UIViewControllers get a navigationController for free?

Comment: UINavigationController is not included in a UIViewController. The property is a pointer to the UINavigationController if there is one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void) clickButton 
{
    NSLog(@"Clicked Button");
    MyFirstController *myViewController = [[MyFirstController alloc] init];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
    [myViewController release];
}
```

Then after go into the MyFirstController.m file and

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil 
{
    if(self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])
    {
        self.title = @"My First View";
    }
    return self;
}
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You havent used or mention NIB file in that controller..Add NIB file or else make set root view controller of a navigation with a view controller and push the view controller

Comment: you don't need nibs. You can use nibs but it's not like it's a required approach.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your IBAction method a little bit as,

```
 - (void) clickButton 
    {
        NSLog(@"Clicked Button");
        MyFirstController *myViewController = [[MyFirstController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyFirstController" bundle:nil];
        myViewController.title = @"My First View";
        myViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

        //to push the UIView.
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];

        //[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];
    }
```

Comment: Does this work even if there is no nib file associated with MyFirstController? Do I have to init with nib?